# Different score depending on check box?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

SOLVED (check spreadsheet) Trying to create a grade calculator for personal use. Please see the shared spreadsheet.

Trying to get a different score/sum depending on which check box is clicked. Don't know if this is possible. Open for other solutions. Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vdtNemd2un3bcQyVua1_aQyYQbLtGOuRrha0nKokcvk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if the cell/checkbox is checked is simply : `=if(cell; valueIfTrue; valueIfFalse)`

Score in D11 should SUM the grades values of :

- the 1st semester if D14 is checked (D2/D3)
- the 2nd semester if D15 is checked (D4/D5)
- the 3rd semester if D16 is checked (D6/D7)

And of course all 3 semester if all are checked.

[image: Problematic]

**Formula**

```
= SUM(if(D14;ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D3; F2:G7; 2; 0)));0);if(D15;ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D4:D5; F2:G7; 2; 0)));0);if(D16;ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D6:D7; F2:G7; 2; 0)));0))
```